# How to configure ArgoCD Hooks for a child app using "App of Apps" Pattern

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I use [app of apps pattern](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/cluster-bootstrapping/#app-of-apps-pattern) so my main-app looks like this:

- main-argocd-app

  - first-argocd-app
  - second-argocd-app

The first-argocd-app is marked as argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "1"

The second-argocd-app is marked as argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "2"

I want to run a job as a hook after first-argocd-app and before second-argocd-app.

There are 3 phases (preSync, Sync, postSync) for the main-argocd-app.
Are there also 3 phases for each child argocd-app? If so, **how can I define the hook to run in-between child argocd-apps?**

I tried to mark my job with:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "1"
    argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PostSync
```

That does not work because the job runs at the end of everything. I guess the "PostSync" refers to the main-argocd-app and not the first-argocd-app. Is there a way to configure the hooks for each child argocd-app? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Change the sync-wave to 1 and 3, and create a new app on sync-wave 2 which performs the job. Or modify app1 to include the job there.

Comment: Apps in an app of apps do not wait for components of child apps to sync. rather, only the `application.yml` manifests are applied in an order specified, but that has nothing to do w/ the components owned by child application manifests

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did create the hook as a [Helm hook](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/) of type "post-install", as part of the first-argocd-app's chart.